# How to download 2 files that have same file names but different capital letters to mac?

Tags: macos, file, duplicates, filenames

I have downloaded two files as a zip to my Mac. The file names are:

```
stack overflow.xml
Stack Overflow.xml
```

But when I unzip the file (Archive.zip), there's only one file unzipped (stack overflow.xml). How do I fix this issue?

Should I set the Mac system somewhere as case sensitive or something?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Just checking, your not unzipping on a FAT USB/thumb drive?

Answer (score 0):

It should be present. If both the filenames are same then you have `(1)` at the end of the filename. The file names are case-sensitive. So, there should be no problem with the files you have mentioned. BTW, even if your files have same name, then as I mentioned above it should have `(1)` at the end of the file name.

Just copy those zip's into a new folder and try to unzip it again.You might be missing something.

P.S: If possible provide the link.

Comment: You might expect this behaviour, but at least on Yosemite it doesn't work that way. Rather it effectively just unpacks one of the files ("effectively" as it probably unpacks both but overwrites). Also tested with The Unarchiver and it too produced only one file.

Comment: @CRD I checked on El Capitan. They must have changed after Yosemite I think.

Comment: Strange, I've tested on Mavericks, Yosemite and El Capitan and only one file results. So I'm seeing what the OP sees, and you're seeing something different... My test ZIP contains just two files differing only in case, and no folders.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

1. Using Disk Utility create a new blank disk image selecting *OS X
   Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled)* as the format.
2. Copy your ZIP archive to this disk image.
3. Unzip.
4. Rename files which differ only in case.
5. Copy files to wherever you want them.
6. Trash the disk image.

*[Note: When testing this we found Disk Utility sometimes failed to create a case-sensitive volume. If this happens you can select the disk in Disk Utility, then the Partition tab, and erase the partition again specifying OS X Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled) as the format.]*

HTH